# Install VSFTPD SERVER in Red Hat 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64

Tags: linux, ftp, redhat-enterprise-linux, vsftpd, redhat-classic

I want to install VSFTPD SERVER in Red Hat  2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64 (the FTP server for Unix-like systems, including Linux)

so I did this:

```
[root@teatre ~]# yum install vsftpd
Loaded plugins: package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
guerrilla_Custom_custom                                                                                                                                                                                               | 1.8 kB     00:00
guerrilla_Icinga_EPEL_Icinga_EPEL_6                                                                                                                                                                                   | 1.8 kB     00:00
guerrilla_Red_Hat_EPEL_Red_Hat_EPEL_6                                                                                                                                                                                 | 2.5 kB     00:00
rhel-6-server-rpms                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 2.0 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vsftpd.x86_64 0:2.2.2-24.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                              Arch                                                 Version                                                    Repository                                                        Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 vsftpd                                               x86_64                                               2.2.2-24.el6                                               rhel-6-server-rpms                                               156 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 156 k
Installed size: 340 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
vsftpd-2.2.2-24.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                        | 156 kB     00:00
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
** Found 4 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_162-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_152-fcs.x86_64
2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_172-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_162-fcs.x86_64
2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_181-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_172-fcs.x86_64
2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_191-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_181-fcs.x86_64
  Installing : vsftpd-2.2.2-24.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                1/1
Uploading Package Profile
  Verifying  : vsftpd-2.2.2-24.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                1/1

Installed:
  vsftpd.x86_64 0:2.2.2-24.el6

Complete!
```

I now I want to config it but I can't find the file `vsftpd.ftpusers`, anywhere

```
#  find . -name vsftpd.ftpusers
#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For different purposes you have two files with users:

```
/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
/etc/vsftpd/user_list
```

First is generic, used by PAM, second is confgurable in main `vsftpd` config